# How to modify attributes before passing them to a superclass constructor?

Tags: java

### The general question:

Given a class like so:

```
public class Super {
    private String value;
    public Super(String initialValue)
    {
        this.value = initialValue;
    }
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And a subclass like so:

```
public class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub(String initialValue)
    {
        super(initialValue);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify `initialValue` before calling the `super()` method?

### Here's my specific use case:

I'm writing a small wrapper ExoPlayer, like so:

```
public class BFPlayer extends PlayerView {
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    public BFPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.BFPlayer);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);

        this.setPlayer(player);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "TODO: USER AGENT STRING"));

        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(attributes.getString(R.styleable.BFPlayer_videoSrc)));

        player.prepare(videoSource);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}
```

ExoPlayer's `PlayerView` View expects attributes (in the `layout.xml` file) to use snake case. For example:

- `use_artwork`
- `default_artwork`
- `hide_on_touch`
- etc

However the ***vast majority*** of default attributes for native Views use camel case:

- `addStatesWithChildren`
- `alwaysDrawnWithCache`
- `animateLayoutChanges`
- `animateCache`
- `clipChildren`
- `clipToPadding`
- etc

Therefore for consistency I would like to replace the ExoPlayer attributes with identical camel case attributes:

- `useArtwork`
- `defaultArtwork`
- `hideOnTouch`
- etc

However because `super()` must be called before any other code in the constructor, I don't have an opportunity to modify the AttributeSet before the superclass initializes:

```
    public BFPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        AttributeSet modifiedAttrs = camelToSnake(attrs);
        super(context, modifiedAttrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
```

Is there a trick to this? Or is it simply impossible?

Comment: Use a static method to modify the arguments

Comment: To answer general case, you could use `super(yourMethod(initialValie))` where `yourMethod(..)` would return modified version of `initialValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you would do something like:

```
class Sub extends Super {
  private static String massageArgument(String incoming) { 
    return incoming.replaceAll("foo", "bar"); 
  }

  public Sub(String incoming) {
    super(massageArgument(incoming));
  }
```

And note: that method needs to be static! You can't use a non-static method within that call to the super constructor in Sub. As any non-static method might expect that it operates on **fully initialized** objects. Which you don't have, when you invoke the method *before* the "this" and the "super" constructor were invoked and could do their initialisation work!

The other option would be to make the Sub constructor *private*, and have a static factory method that manipulates the incoming string, and then calls `new Sub()` right away with the massaged input.

Comment: It **has** to be static.  You can't refer to an instance method when invoking the constructor via super.

Comment: I would not have thought of using a method.  I ran into the problem of needing to change a value prior to invoking `super()` just two hours ago. :)

Comment: You mentioned that the method needs to be static, but in your example you didn't make the method static :)

Comment: @stevendesu great observation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
package Sample;

public class Parent{

    public Parent() {
        System.out.println("Parent default constructor called");
    }

    public Parent(String value) {
        System.out.println("Parent patametrized (String) constructor called value :: "+value);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Child("Sample ");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{

    public Child() {
        System.out.println("Child default constructor called");
    }

    public Child(String value) {
        super(value+" converted from child "); // either maipulate inside or call a static method
        System.out.println("Child parametrized (String) constructor called");
    }
}
```